# How to read the Section from Config file from c# code

Tags: c#

While reading the config section through c# , Am getting an error in Line 1.

`The application relative virtual path '~' is not allowed here.`

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
    System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");  
SystemWebSectionGroup grp = (SystemWebSectionGroup)config.GetSectionGroup("system.web");
```

Comment: can you show what the section in the config file looks like as well

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the value of "~" is not allowed when calling OpenWebConfiguration, but that's just a guess from reading the error message. The documentation for OpenWebConfiguration ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) says to pass `null` if you want the root web.config.